# Is it possible to upsert PriceBookEntry

Tags: apex, pricebook, product, pricebookentry

I have tried upserting PriceBookEntry

```
PricebookEntry p = new PricebookEntry();
List<PricebookEntry> lstp = new List<PricebookEntry> {};
 Pricebook2 pb = [select Id, IsActive from PriceBook2 where IsStandard=True];
 PricebookEntry sp = new PricebookEntry();
                     sp.Pricebook2id=pb.id;
                     sp.Product2Id='01t28000001rYB5';
                     sp.UnitPrice=76.09;
                     sp.IsActive=true;

lstp.add(sp); 
                                    p.product2id = '01t28000001rYB5';
                                    p.pricebook2id = '01s28000009KhaR';
                                    p.IsActive=true;
                                    p.UnitPrice= 110.08;

lstp.add(p);
upsert lstp;
```

**Note:** For the first time it is inserting correctly. But for the next time when I run this program, it is showing the below error message as

> System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, This price definition already exists in this
>   price book: []

Am I doing anything wrong?? Or else Suggest me if there any other possible way to upsert PriceBookEntry.

Comment: Try to upsert like this -  upsert lstp {externalid/matchingid field name};

Comment: I have already tried your suggestion... the same error captured

Comment: System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Unable to create/update fields: Product2Id. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.: [Product2Id]

Comment: You can apply the suggestion mention in the following link : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73881/can-i-upsert-pricebookentry-records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to upsert an sObject you'll need the objects Id or another external key field. Some options to achieve what you want:

- Create a external Id field and populate it with a unique combination of fields (example: Product2Id + Pricebook2Id) and use that field on your upsert call `upsert lstp New_External_Field__c`
- Query for Pricebook entry and retrieve the Id if they exist. And set it on the object you're trying to upsert

Answer (score 3):

In the Pricebookentry, Pricebook2Id and Product2Id are unique combination,  so can't be modified.

You can delete an entry and can add new entry

Comment: Yes Santanu that is correct. Upvoting your answer. Dominic once you delete old entry you could upsert new entry based on any created external id.